# Convert this code into a One-Liner?

Tags: powershell

Do yall know how to convert the below code into a one liner? I've seen it been done with similar code. The reason for doing so, I want to execute this remotely.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNoCancel
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
$MessageBody = "!Attention! Our Network is having Connectivity Issues. NO ETA on when it's going to be fixed. Sorry for the inconvinience. Thank you "
$MessageTitle = "Network Connectivity Issue"

$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
```

Comment: For executing remote code you can use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1), regardless of the length/size of the code.

Comment: @DarkLite1 I maybe thinking too much into it, I just really don't know how its done. Would you care to show me? that way I can learn how to do it instead of getting a free answer?

Comment: @Abesaurous there is no reason to have this be a one-liner, especially not when the text is most of its length, just wrap it all in `Invoke-Command` or put it in a `.ps1` and run it..

Comment: Join all lines and separate them by a semicolon (`;`) : `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework; $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNoCancel; $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning; $MessageBody = "!Attention! Our Network is having Connectivity Issues. NO ETA on when it's going to be fixed. Sorry for the inconvinience. Thank you "; $MessageTitle = "Network Connectivity Issue"; $Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at assembling the code into a scriptblock, then pass that to your remote session.

ref: http://www.padisetty.com/2014/05/all-about-powershell-scriptblock.html